# Is there any way to get access to the icons used in the Visual Studio Shell?

Tags: visual-studio, shell, integration

I'm working on a project that uses the Visual Studio Shell, with internal editors, etc, implemented with WPF.  Is there any way to get access to the icons used by the Visual Studio Shell so that I can place them on my controls to have a more consistent look and feel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, but have you seen the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx)?

> The Visual Studio 2010 Image Library contains application images that appear in Microsoft Windows, the Office system, Microsoft Visual Studio, and other Microsoft software. You can use this set of over 1,000 images to create applications that look visually consistent with Microsoft software.

And:

> The Visual Studio Image Library is installed on your computer together with Visual Studio. To access the files in the image library, you must extract them from VS2010ImageLibrary.zip. This file is typically installed in ..\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary\1033.

It is not included in Express editions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Icons Extract was free and easy to use.

It will recursively loop through the entire Visual Studio folder structure.
So you don't have to guess or know what files to extract from.

[Download](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html)

[image: Main Screen]

Answer (score 0):

A free program named [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) can extract icons from any executable or a dll file. For example here are the icons it found in the devenv.exe executable:

[image: IcoFX Extract Dialogue]